# building destruction slow motion

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

is there a way to make the building destruction go slow motion on a specific frame? I have a project that I wanted to make the building destruction normal at first but at frame 8 , go slow motion? thank you

also I want the pieces to go all together not only one piece as I don't know how to make all pieces slow motion together , best regard
[image]

unfortunately I cant really add the blend file here , as its too large[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can animate the the *Speed* property of the *Rigid Body World*:

[image]